# Changing storage path for uploads in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4, laravel-form

I want to have users be able to upload files to my Laravel app, and I am curious about changing the storage path for the upload form.

Are there any security concerns I should have about changing this path?

Also, if I just wanted to change the storage path for files uploaded by this form only, is there a simple way for me to do that?

(and not change logs, sessions, etc)?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new public folder, set path in  bootstrap/paths.php. This way you are keeping your app folders separated from Laravel Folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can define it in bootstrap/paths.php:

```
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

Don't forget to set the required read/write permissions for the new directory.